# Is String#pluralize idempotent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, plural, idempotent

That is, for any String `string`, does the following hold?

```
string.pluralize == string.pluralize.pluralize
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Don Roby: You mean, by checking for every possible string?

Comment: I meant for a reasonable set, as in Ryan Bigg's answer.

Comment: Try person. It might return person -> people -> peoples, since people is a legitimate plural of people.

Comment: Person doesn't break. Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

pluralize is NOT idempotent.  I can prove it by example (courtesy of a personal Facebook posting that hit some language geeks).

```
"taxi".pluralize
=> "taxis"
"taxis".pluralize
=> "taxes"
"taxi".pluralize.pluralize
=> "taxes"
```

So "taxi" (the thing that drives you around) to "taxis" (an arrangement or order) to "taxes" (the proper pluralization of "taxis").  I'm sure there are other examples, but they are certainly hard to come by.

Not looking for score or acceptance on this answer, but I couldn't really fit this nicely into the comments on Ryan's post.

Comment: As of Rails 5 (and maybe earlier?), this counterexample no longer works.

   `"taxi".pluralize` => `"taxis"` and
   `"taxi".pluralize.pluralize` => `"taxis"`

Comment: What happens if I want to pluralize taxis?  Probably still the right call though.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot think of a case where it wouldn't.

I just tried the following words and it doesn't change after a second pluralizaation. However, some of them *do* "break" in interesting ways because of two reasons: 1) Rails' pluralization rules are actually quite dumb and 2) English is ***hard***.

- analysis -> analyses -> analysis
- media -> media -> media
- news -> news -> news
- cactii -> cactiis -> cactiis
- criterion -> criterions -> criterions
- foot -> foots -> foots
- loaf -> loafs -> loafs
- person -> people -> people

Comment: What's the chain for "person"? `person -> people -> people`?

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem consistent to me. The plural of `people` is `peoples`, not `people`. Maybe they actually force it to have this property.

Comment: @NiklasB: The plural of person is people . There is no word as "Peoples". Brush up your English .. :)

Comment: Welcome to Computational Linguistics :-)

Comment: @NiklasB. : Its can be argument. We back in India havent encountered Peoples yet !!

Comment: @Mithun: Hehe :P I somehow remembered that from some long-past English lesson.

Comment: The pluralize is particularly bad at things like non-count nouns.  For example: advice, furniture, oxygen.  The pluralizer adds an "s" to all of them.

Comment: Nice set of examples here. I haven't been able to find a counterexample either. (Btw, it should be "analysis -> analyses -> analyses".)

Comment: "taxi" to "taxis" to "taxes" for the counterexample!

Comment: In more recent versions of Rails, the counterexample from another answer no longer works, so you could add it to your list: taxi -> taxis -> taxis